# CGMutablePathRef Memory Management

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, path, quartz-graphics

Do I need to release a CGMutablePathRef when I'm done with it? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [CGPath docs](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html), there are both CGPathRetain and CGPathRelease functions.